# Integrating Google In-app billing in cocos2dx game

Tags: cocos2d-x

I developed a game using Cocos2dx for iOS. 
I porting my game to android using ADT.I want to implement IAP for my game .I studied Google in-app billing .got https://github.com/robotmedia/AndroidBillingLibrary  and https://github.com/soomla/cocos2dx-store .

But it is in java. my cocos2dx game based on c++.
I need to know how can i implement this in my game or else point me in right direction for implementing in-app purchase for my android game

Answer (score 0):

you can use sdkbox library as a thirdparty to handle in app billing.
http://www.sdkbox.com/